# Putting Prints in order in python

Tags: python

I need help with this problem in python.

I have this code:

```
from random import randint
numplayers=int(input('Please enter number of players here: '))
banker=randint(1,numplayers)
for x in range(1,numplayers+1):
    if x==banker:
        print('Player',x,'is the banker')
    else:
        print('Player',x,'is not the banker')
```

So this code prints whether or not a player is the banker but with an order from `1 to numplayers`
Let's say that player 4 is the banker. How can I print this:

```
*player 4: you are the banker
*player 1: you are not the banker
*player 2: you are not the banker 
*player 3: you are not the banker
-----
```

In other words I want to print first the player that is the banker then the other ones.

Comment: Well you know who the `banker` is. So first print that. Than print everyone that are ***not*** the banker. hint: you can check `if x != banker`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, print the user who is the banker, then loop it through while checking it's not the banker.

So, You can do this:

```
from random import randint
numplayers=int(input('Please enter number of players here: '))
banker=randint(1,numplayers)
print(f"Player {banker}: you are the banker")
for x in range(1,numplayers+1):
    if x!=banker:
        print(f'Player {x}: you are not the banker')
```

If you want it inside the loop:

```
from random import randint
numplayers=int(input('Please enter number of players here: '))
banker=randint(1,numplayers)
for x in range(1,numplayers+1):
    if x == 1:
        print(f"Player {banker}: you are the banker")
    if x!=banker:
        print(f'Player {x}: you are not the banker')
```

Comment: if this was helpful, please accept it by clicking the check mark

Answer (score 0):

I would print the banker before the loop, like so:

```
from random import randint
numplayers=int(input('Please enter number of players here: '))
banker=randint(1,numplayers)

print(f"Player {banker}: you are the banker")

for x in range(1,numplayers+1):
    if x==banker:
        continue
    else:
        print(f'Player {x}: you are not the banker')
```

Comment: Why check a condition just to `continue`? Why not check the reversed condition (`x != banker`)?

Comment: yes, you could equally do that. I left the logical structure the same so it's easier for the questioner to follow the change I made.

Comment: thank you but is there something i can do to print the program i asked for with the banker inside the for loop?

Comment: @PanagiotisStavropoulos Check my answer please.

Comment: is there a particular reason you want the logic to be inside the loop?

Comment: @PirateNinjas im trying to program a dice game so i want to put the whole for loop inside a while loop

Comment: You could still put the above in your while loop I think. Thanks for filling me in!